# Customize PLAY_SESSION cookie maxAge per request

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to set different `maxAge` for the session `PLAY_SESSION` cookie in different requests by different values? Not globally as described in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsSession but per request change its value manually.

```
Ok.withSession(request.session + ("sessionToken" -> token))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on Play, and used the java version, but after searching i saw that there is a [SessionCookieBaker](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/SessionCookieBaker.html) that has a maxAge value member, you may start from there.